# How can I check multiple textbox if null or empty in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, null, textbox

How can I check multiple textbox if null or empty in Javascript ? I should know which textbox is filled

Comment: show your html markup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery .each function with a selector pointing to all the input elements with type "text". Something like this:

```
var nonNullInputs = new Array();
$(':text').each(function (index, value) {
    if ($(this).val() != null) {
        //get the id of the non null text input and push it for example in an array
        //the index parameter returns the number of the input element by order in the form,
        //the value parameter return the value
        nonNullInputs.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
//now you have an array named nonNullInputs with all the inputs with type text which are not empty.
```

I Hope this helps :-)